# Ubuntu 16.04 - Minecraft Crashing

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm not sure what's happening. I'm on Asus TP300LD laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, I have oracle Java 8 installed.

Here is the crash readout for Minecraft launcher

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why did you do that?
Time: 2/27/17 9:27 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Could not choose GLX13 config
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)
```

**A detailed walkthrough of the error:**

```
-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.initDefaultPeerInfo(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.(LinuxDisplayPeerInfo.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.createPeerInfo(LinuxDisplay.java:828)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.DrawableGL.setPixelFormat(DrawableGL.java:61)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:846)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bes.ap(SourceFile:600)
    at bes.an(SourceFile:436)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bes.a(SourceFile:383)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11.2
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 4.8.0-39-generic
    Java Version: 1.8.0_121, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 421540560 bytes (402 MB) / 523501568 bytes (499 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M -Xms512M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.11.2
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU:
```

Comment: Do you have the drivers for your graphics card installed?

Comment: Not an answer, but I’d guess this is a problem with Hybrid Graphics 
(your laptop has both Intel and NVIDIA graphics chips). See [Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia 361.42 proprietary drivers crash](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/2736215-ubuntu-16-04-and-nvidia-361-42-proprietary-drivers), [Google: Could not choose GLX13 config](https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=Could+not+choose+GLX13+config). This might be another line of enquiry worth following.

Comment: @JosephSible How can i see it?, PD: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

`OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.`

I get the above error when I change my screen resolution from the default. Changing it back to the maximum resolution fixes the problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenJDK 1.8.0_151 and Minecraft 1.12.2.